# Trying to find error in Java Swing program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

So this is my program... It's a way to enter and list marathon runners. Now I'm getting an error when using the "Ny" button (http://gyazo.com/e29517af6befd6242d86e6fe1dc5aae1). Here's the error code: http://gyazo.com/9f80885d41db38cfa5502fe911f6a893.

I think the problems is between the "Form" panel and the listener. There may be unreachable code somewhere? I had this working the other day but I lost the code. Now it doesn't work.
The idea is that the "ny" button shows the user a panel "Form", but instead I get the rror.

I'm a huge noob, so I expect it's some obvious syntax error I just can't seem to spot.
Any feedback is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Maraton extends JFrame{

JTextArea display; 
JButton visa;

ArrayList <Tävlande> list = new ArrayList <Tävlande>();




Maraton(){
    super("Kista Maraton");
    display = new JTextArea();
    display.setEditable(false);

    add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(new JScrollPane(display),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(300, 400);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    JPanel nedre = new JPanel ();
    JPanel höger = new JPanel();

    add(nedre, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(höger, BorderLayout.EAST);
    höger.setLayout(new BoxLayout(höger, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    nedre.setBackground( new Color(246,246,246) );
    nedre.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(200,200,200)));


    JButton ny = new JButton("Ny");
    ny.addActionListener(new NyLis());

    JButton visa = new JButton("Visa");
    visa.addActionListener(new VisaLis());
    visa.setEnabled(false);

    JButton nyTid = new JButton("Ny Tid");

    nedre.add(ny);
    nedre.add(visa);
    nedre.add(nyTid);



    JRadioButton StartNrRb = new JRadioButton("Startnr");
    JRadioButton NamnRb = new JRadioButton("Namn");
    JRadioButton ÅlderRb = new JRadioButton("Ålder");
    JRadioButton TidRb = new JRadioButton("Tid");

    höger.add(StartNrRb);
    höger.add(NamnRb);
    höger.add(ÅlderRb);
    höger.add(TidRb);

    ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup();
    bg1.add(NamnRb);
    bg1.add(StartNrRb);
    bg1.add(ÅlderRb);
    bg1.add(TidRb);

}

class Form2 extends JPanel{
    JTextField startNrFält;
    JTextField tidFält;

    Form2(){
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JPanel rad0 = new JPanel();
        rad0.add(new JLabel("Start Nummer: "));
        rad0.add(new JLabel("Tid: "));
        rad0.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rad0, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        rad0.add(startNrFält);
        rad0.add(tidFält);
        add(rad0);

    }
}

class Form extends JPanel{
    JTextField namnFält;
    JTextField landFält;
    JTextField ålderFält;




    Form(){

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel rad1 = new JPanel();
        rad1.add(new JLabel("Namn: "));
        namnFält = new JTextField(15);
        rad1.add(namnFält);
        add(rad1);

        JPanel rad2 = new JPanel();
        rad2.add(new JLabel("Land: "));
        landFält = new JTextField(15);
        rad2.add(landFält);
        add(rad2);

        JPanel rad3 = new JPanel();
        rad3.add(ålderFält);
        rad3.add(new JLabel("Ålder: "));
        ålderFält = new JTextField(5);
        rad3.add(ålderFält);
        add(rad3);


    }

}



class NyLis implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave){
        Form f = new Form();

        int svar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, f);


        String namn = f.namnFält.getText();
        String land = f.landFält.getText();
        int ålder = Integer.parseInt(f.ålderFält.getText());


        Tävlande tv = new Tävlande (namn,land,ålder);
        list.add(tv);
        visa.setEnabled(true);
    }

}





class VisaLis implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave) {
        display.setText("");
        for (Tävlande t : list){
            display.append(t.toString()+"\n");
        }
    }

}

class NyTidLis implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave) {

        Form f2 = new Form();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, f2);

    }

}




public static void main (String []args){
    new Maraton();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you embed the images into your post; that way they will last longer and be easier to see?

Comment: So, something that you are trying to access (around line 116) is not initialised. Do we have to find that line and debug it for you?

Comment: Check what follows `JPanel rad3 = new JPanel();`

Comment: Post all information relating to your question in the forum not on a different website with a link to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to add a `null` object to your `JPanel` when you click the `ny` button. The offending code is found in the constructor for your `Form` object:

```
rad3.add(ålderFält);
ålderFält = new JTextField(5); //NO! Create the JTextFieldObject first
rad3.add(ålderFält);
```

Alter the code to the following:

```
ålderFält = new JTextField(5);
rad3.add(ålderFält);
rad3.add(ålderFält);
```

And you should have no problems (or at least the code runs for me).

You also have a problem with your `visa` button. You're declaring an entirely new `JButton` in your constructor, which will lead to more `NullPointerException`s when you try to enable it.

In the future, read your stack trace a little more closely. Sometimes you have to dig through a few lines of it to find out where, exactly, in your code you're going wrong. This is especially true when you're doing graphical stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining the JButton visa in the constructor of your class on this line:

```
JButton visa = new JButton("Visa");
```

This is distinct from the visa variable defined class level (here this.visa, and visa represent two seperate JButtons), which you attempt to access (uninitialized) in your NyLis actionListener.

Change the aforementioned line to:

```
visa = new JButton("Visa");
```